# Vuetify from validation,How can i fix validation Function error message?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Using validation methods in Vuetify, but error message say below↓
I just wanna make validation check form, and install the function that
push the 'submit' button and checked all text-field validation.

I think my problem is methods of submit's validation() in my code below.
I followed the Vuetify website method, but error message displayed.

Please someone help me.

[error message]
`Property 'validate' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'. Property 'validate' does not exist on type 'Vue'`.

```
    <template>
  <v-form ref="validation_check">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
          <v-text-field
            label="name"
            v-model="text"
            :rules="[textValidation.required,textValidation.limit_lemgth]"
            counter="10"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
          <v-text-field
            label="phone"
            v-model="phone"
            :rules="[textValidation.required,textValidation.text_length2]"
            counter="7"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-btn @click="submit">submit</v-btn>
          <span v-if="success">Congurats★Validation is no prob!!</span>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class form extends Vue {
  text: string = "";
  phone?: number;
  success:boolean=false;

  textValidation={
     required:(v:string)=>!!v||'this is required',
     limit_lemgth:(v:string)=>v.length<=10||'Name must be less than 10 characters',    
     text_length2:(v:string)=>v.length<=10||'Phone number must be less than 7 characters',
  };

  submit(){
    if(this.$refs.validation_check.validate()){
        this.success=true
    }else{
        this.success=false;
    }
    
}


}
</script>
```

My English is not good enough, please accept my apology.

Comment: are you sure about textValidation.limit_lemgth? or even textValidation.text_length2? please check them, so there is no typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to using Typescript. As you have not specified what type `this.$refs.validation_check` is, it will look for default, like you get in error: `'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'` and correctly tells you that `validate()` does not exist on any of them.

Vuetify does not (at the moment at least), have typescript support provided for their elements, so you would need to create your own type. I suggest that, rather than for example using `any`. That would defeat the purpose of TypeScript...

So I suggest the following, create your type, name it as you wish:

```ts
export type VuetifyForm = Vue & { validate: () => void };
```

If you want to add more functions that are provided you can chain them with `&`, like:

```ts
export type VuetifyForm = Vue & { validate: () => void } & { reset: () => void }
```

... as many as you need from the functions (or all of them).

Then in your component, import the type, and specify `this.$refs.validation_check` as that type and your error should be gone:

```ts
import { VuetifyForm } from 'your/path';

// ....  

submit() {
  if ((this.$refs.validation_check as VuetifyForm).validate()) {
    this.success = true;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering!! I really understand! Thank you so much!!